# What is this 3D text effect called?

Tags: text, effects, style-identification, technique

I need some help defining the technique used in this image.

[image: the word play with an effect added]

I call it a 3d drop shadow but that isn't the best or correct term to use for this graphic.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply call it **3D extruded text**.

Comment: Why 3d it could just be 2d extruded too ;)

Comment: Thank you both for your help either of these options make it easier to communicate the style to my client.

Comment: @joojaa, yeah you're right. Or just "extruded text". But it's such a short answer - I needed all the characters I could get :-).